# Mentions Auto Suggesting da jquery a php

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I'm making a change to a text area and thanks to this plugin I can mention users from a db after entering @ in a textarea you place the complete code.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="bootstrap-suggest.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<textarea class="form-control" rows="8" id="example-1"></textarea>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-suggest.js"></script>
<script>
var users = [
  {username: 'lodev09', fullname: 'Jovanni Lo'}
];
$('#example-1').suggest('@', {
  data: users,
  map: function(user) {
    return {
      value: user.username,
      text: '<strong>'+user.username+'</strong> <small>'+user.fullname+'</small>'
    }
  }
})

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

in the user variable there are the search fields by default, I ask you for help, which instead of the defaul fields in the variable, the search is done in a php page, the data to search from my database sql, how can I change the code? how do I change defaul fields with dynamic fields taken from the database? Thanks I hope you help me

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to search on a php page, how can I do? work without the default results

Comment: I rephrase my question: you are expected to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example of what you have actually tried to do to achieve your objective and let us know what errors you are encountering that you've been unable to solve. Stackoverflowers are happy to help in that case, as this is a learning environment, not a code writing service.

Comment: I can not connect to the database

Answer (score 0):

So I pretty much just followed the documentation on http://lodev09.github.io/bootstrap-suggest/#api

I wanted to include `Axios` as that's a more preferred way to fetch data in large scale applications.

and in their example `return $.getJSON("users/data.json", { q: q });` using `q` by default will look up all the keys in the array. You can specify if you only want to search say for `username` with `{ username: q }`

Here's my working db example you can use from [{} myjson](http://myjson.com/18vsxq)

Now the part that'd you change for getting this to work with your php backend is the api and api endpoint you've setup.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link href="bootstrap-suggest.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" id="example-1">type after ->  @</textarea>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://lodev09.github.io/bootstrap-suggest/bower_components/bootstrap-suggest/bootstrap-suggest.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('#example-1').suggest('@', {
      data: function(q) {
        if (q) {
          return $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/18vsxq', {
            q: q
          }).then(function(Response) {
            return Response.users
          });
        }
      },
      map: function(user) {
        return {
          value: user.username,
          text: '<strong>' + user.username + '</strong> <small>' + user.fullname + '</small>'
        }
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

anyways hopes this helps,

-Brendan

Comment: thank you very much, I have 5000 users to show, on the recall page, how can I search for the name using select sql? through while, how I connect user to the database

Comment: I do not understand how I can search on a php file in my database, help I would like an example